# How to create columns dynamically in MVVM

Tags: mvvm

i have to create a dialog where columns has to be generated at run time, earlier i was using WPF data grid so generating columns at runtime was not a problem. Now i have to use View Model i need to have properties for whatever fields i want to display in view as columns. the number of columns are not known at design time, its not possible for set binding for the data grid.It will be crazy if i create properties at runtime using reflection, is there any way that i can bind runtime generated fields to a data grid column.

Comment: Have you used `AutoGeneratedColumns = true`?

Comment: I am not using WPF grid, its Xceed data grid which doesn't have such property. it creates columns for Properties defined in ViewModel.

Comment: Is there an clear purpose of using third part components? If yes - it's more Xceed question rather than MVVM.

Comment: It's called `AutoCreateColumns` on the xceed Grid. Try that... Otherwise look at Mike's Answer. ExpandoObject appears to be a good idea if you are on .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on .NET 4 you can use ExpandoObject. It implements INotifyPropertyChanged for you.